# Calculate percent change from initial month

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has monthly data for customers.  I want to calculate the percent change of users from subsequent months back to their initial start month.  For example, a customer may have 10 users in month one, 14 users in month 2, 20 users in month 3, and 5 users in month 4.  I'd like to calculate the percent change from each subsequent month back to the initial month (and not month over month change). Is this something that mysql can handle?

Comment: Please provide the code you've attempted and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Assuming following table structure

sql> CREATE TABLE pct (x int(5)) ENGINE=MyISAM ;

sql> INSERT INTO pct VALUES (10),(14),(20),(5) ;

sql> SET @fmonth=-9999 ;

sql>  select x, ((x*100)/fmonth)-100 as pctcng from (select x, if(@fmonth<0,@fmonth:=x, @fmonth) as fmonth  from pct) as pct ;

```
+------+----------+
| x    | pctcng   |
+------+----------+
|   10 |   0.0000 |
|   14 |  40.0000 |
|   20 | 100.0000 |
|    5 | -50.0000 |
+------+----------+
```

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Make sure to reset @fmonth to value not in your actual data. In this example I have it as negative 9999.